# Translating a widget isn't smooth

Tags: flutter

I am using a widget which starts off from the centre of the screen. I want the widget to move from centre to the top and vice-versa as user drags the widget.

I have wrapped my widget with Gesture detector and also with Transform widget whose Y value gets changed as user drags.

I am using value notifier when the Y position changes as user drags. The widget drags as expected.

The problem is that the scroll of the widget is not smooth. I have tried using Animation controller but I am not very sure how that would fit here.

Is there a way I could use scroll animation on my widget so that its smooth?

Below is my widget that I want to translate on drag:

```
Transform(
  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, widget.verticalOffset, 0),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
    child: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onVerticalDragUpdate: widget.handleDragUpdate,
            onVerticalDragEnd: _handleVerticalDragEnd,
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: controller,
                physics: _getScrollPhysics(context),
                itemCount: widget.songs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return buildSongRow(widget.songs[index]);
              }
            )
          )
       ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Have you tried building it in Profile mode? The debug mode is incredibly slow with many things.

Comment: Well thanks a lot that made it work. Although if something is not smooth in debug mode and then works fins in the profile or release mode, is that okay or I still need to optimise the code.

Comment: I think you're fine as long as it works well in profile mode. If you look at the performance module it actually tells you to make sure you test in profile mode. This is probably because debug is using JIT compilation so you can have hot-reload functionality.

Comment: cool. You can post your answer then and I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running things in debug mode this is a likely result. To make sure your animation is running as smooth as you hope then you'll want to run things in profile mode.